# Rails 3.2.1 app in production running slow

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-3, performance

I have a Rails app running on rackspace on postgreSQL.

It is really slow.

On special requests it uses up to 4 sec to respond

I have installed new relic.

I can see that for example the index action of some controllers are the slowest. They are really simple with a few finds.

So, I really don't understand what slows it down.

I wonder if you all can mention some gems that can find performance issues?

I know about bullet, that helps with finding n+1 queries to the database, but that is not my problem.

By request I add the index action of the projects controller(average of 4000 ms response time)

```
def index
    @firm = current_firm
    @projects = current_user.projects.is_active
    @customers = @firm.customers
    @project = Project.new
    @todo = Todo.new
end
```

The is_active method is a scope in the model

```
scope :is_active, where(["active = ?", true])
```

From the application controller I have some helpers and before_filters. One of them could be the problem(or something else) That's why I'd like to have some tools for tracking down performance issues.

**Update**
 looking at the production.log I see

```
Rendered logs/_list_header.html.erb (0.3ms)
Rendered logs/_log.html.erb (127.7ms)
Rendered private/log_range.js.erb (721.2ms)
Completed 200 OK in 836ms (Views: 733.2ms | ActiveRecord: 43.9ms)

Processing by ProjectsController#index as HTML
Rendered projects/_index.html.erb (4149.8ms)
Rendered projects/index.html.erb within layouts/application (4157.0ms)
Rendered layouts/_header.html.erb (0.3ms)
Completed 200 OK in 6682ms (Views: 4199.6ms | ActiveRecord: 457.0ms)

Processing by LogsController#stop_tracking as JS
Parameters: xxxxx
Rendered logs/_tracking_partial.html.erb (121.1ms)
Rendered logs/_start_tracking.html.erb (6877.9ms)
Rendered logs/_log.html.erb (43.0ms)
Rendered logs/stop_tracking.js.erb (7224.0ms)
Completed 200 OK in 9968ms (Views: 7617.2ms | ActiveRecord: 455.3ms)
```

look at the last one. A lot of time spent rendering views and js. What can cause this. There is no finds in the views. I just use a instance variable form the controller. And there is less than 20 entries in the database. Could this be caused by a slow internet connection on the computer accessing these views?

Comment: Probably the columns aren't indexed?

Comment: Maybe you can post the code for one of the worst controllers (and maybe your application controller code, too).

Comment: @evfwcqcg Thanks for replying. Can you tell me how to do it or link to a tutorial?

Comment: Where is the Postgresql db installed? Is it yours or you have it as a service?

Comment: What is the amount of data you are dealing with in here? Knowing at least the order of magnitude (10 records, 1000 records, 100000 records) would be helpful

Comment: from new relic, what is the time spent in the database vs the ruby process? the graphs should show both.

Comment: The postgresql is on the same virtual host and it is just installed. Less than ten entries in the database.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem was the asset pipeline

I had some css and js files that was not precompiled. I did not get any error messages, but you have to be accurate with the naming. No "." in the file name and no ".css"

indexing did not help. But, it will probably increase performance when there is more entries in the database.

Answer (score 2):

Probably your Postgresql database service is a crap, or it's far from your app server??

Anyway, you should create indexes! 
How? In your migrations like

```
add_index :costumers, :firm_id
```

You can also add indexes with multiple columns for example

```
add_index :projects, [:user_id, :alive]
```

Here is all the options for `add_index`

> add_index(table_name, column_names, options): Adds a new index with
>   the name of the column. Other options include :name, :unique (e.g. {
>   :name => "users_name_index", :unique => true }) and :order (e.g. {
>   :order => {:name => :desc} }).

Also take in mind that i'm not saying you should create these indexes, they are just examples. You must see from your queries what goes in the where clauses

I haven't find any good information about indexes on docs but here seems to be a nice article on it http://tomafro.net/2009/08/using-indexes-in-rails-index-your-associations

Comment: -Thank you for aswer. I will add indexes, and see if it helps. The postgresql is on the same virtual host and it is just installed. Less than ten entries in the database